# Retrieving ListView to Adaptor across classes

Tags: java, android, listview, adaptor

I am trying to add items to a ListView/Adapter from my MainActivity and use it across ListHelper.

I have it declared in Registrant.

```
public static List<Registrant> searchList = new ArrayList<Registrant>();
```

And then I add to it from MainActivity..

```
Registrant.searchList.add(registrant);
```

Then I try to retrieve this into a listview from the ListHelper.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, Registrant.searchList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But no luck, it is a blank screen?

Any ideas would be helpful.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating object of `CustomListAdapter` class for updating data in ListView data-source. create a method in `CustomListAdapter` class for adding data in List which is used by Adapter as data-source :

In `CustomListAdapter` class add following method:

```
public void addItems(){
   arrList.addAll(Registrant.searchList);
   this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call `addItems` method when want to update data in ListView:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
adapter.addItems();
```

Comment: This lead me in the right direction, however, the problem was  that I had just set the ListView before setting the adapter. Thank you for your help.